# How to get my code to print out only the even numbers in a given integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am trying to write code that when an int is passed through it for example like 256 it only prints out the 2 and the 6 since they are even numbers.

I was having trouble before because I was not converting the int to a string and then back to an int for the for loop to analyze it. as you can see in my code after an integer n is passed through the function I convert it into a string, then make a for loop that converts it back to ints. Then i use if statements to make a modulus operator so only even numbers print out but I cant quite seem to get it right.

```
def evenDigits(n):
    numbers = str(n)
    print(numbers)
    for x in numbers:
        intdigits = int(numbers)
        print(x)
        evennumbers = intdigits % 2
        if evennumbers > 0:
            print("")
        else:
            print(x)
evenDigits(256)
```

If It is possible to fix my code so it does so, show me. also can you write a more better looking for loop code that does the same thing, and as well How would a while loop code for this look like as well?

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped me. I was able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this but the main thing you need to fix is:

```
for x in numbers:
    intdigits = int(x)  #you need to not pass the whole number but the currently iterating num
    print(x)
```

Also, if you are passing the number as an int you could directly do the modulo operations

```
def evenDigits(n):
    #numbers = str(n)  #if this is an int then just use this n
    evennums = []
    while n > 0:
        rem = n % 10
        if rem % 2 == 0:
            evennums.append(rem)
        n = n / 10
print(evennums)  # here you could look at different ways of formatting the prints, like print(','.join(evennums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert each character `x` to an integer, rather than the entire `numbers`:

```
def evenDigits(n):
    numbers = str(n)
    for x in numbers:
        intdigits = int(x)
        evennumbers = intdigits % 2
        if evennumbers == 0:
            print(x)
evenDigits(256)
```

To do this more efficiently, you can use the `__contains__` method of a set of even digit characters as a filter instead:

```
def evenDigits(n):
    return filter(set('02468').__contains__, str(n))

for digit in evenDigits(256):
    print(digit)
```

This outputs:

```
2
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have two small errors in your code:

1. You are printing once too much (therefore also odd numbers are printed).
2. `intdigits` needs to be filled with the actual number `x`.

The corrected code reads

```
def evenDigits(n):
    numbers = str(n)
    print(numbers)
    for x in numbers:
        intdigits = int(x)
        evennumbers = intdigits % 2
        if evennumbers > 0:
            print("")
        else:
            print(x)
evenDigits(256)
```

One more comment: You could write your code a little more concisely. This would make it easier to understand. Instead of defining the new variable `evennumbers` just write

```
if intdigits % 2:
    ...
```

Whenever the modulo returns `0`, this is interpreted as `False`.

Also, you may not want to print anything, if the number is odd. Hence, I would write the code as follows:

```
def evenDigits(n):
    for x in str(n):
        if not int(x) % 2:
            print(x, end='')
    print()
evenDigits(256)
```

The result is `26`.

Answer (score 0):

So for a given number, you can use `num % 10` to kind of "pop" digits off of the ones place, and you can check if that number is divisible by 2 with the mod 2 operation you've already been using:

```py
def evenDigits(n):
    x = n % 10
    while n:
        if not x%2: # Not divisible by 2
            print(x)
        n //= 10 # integer divide by 10 to move to the next digit
        x = n % 10
```

This approach saves you the type conversion at least, and at the end of the loop `n //= 10` will return `0`, breaking the `while` loop.

Furthermore, you can use `str` iteration and the `int` conversion to do this as well:

```py
def evenDigits(n):
    n = str(n)
    for digit in n:
        if not int(digit) % 2:
           print(digit)
```